# How to avoid firewall blockage in Power Query's Parameter Table?

Tags: import, powerquery, firewall

[This powerful custom fnGetParameter function](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/26/building-a-parameter-table-for-power-query/) lets you dynamically inject file names into your queries.

But because of it, the `Data source settings` show `Current Workbook` **instead** of your actual imported files:

[image: Power Query's Data source settings when using dynamic file names]

Thus, as many have commented in that link it can lead to this message, for example if I try to `Merge Queries` i.e. `Table.NestedJoin()`:

> Formula.Firewall: Query '{name}' (step '{step}') references other
> queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please
> rebuild this data combination.

**Sample data**

*cities.csv*

| Name | City |
| --- | --- |
| John | New York |
| Steve | New Jersey |

*cars.csv*

| Name | Car |
| --- | --- |
| Steve | BMW |
| John | Porche |

*Excel itself*

**table name=Parameters**

| Parameter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| cities | c:\users{enter your username}\Downloads\cities.csv |
| cars | c:\users{enter your username}\Downloads\cars.csv |

*cities query*

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(fnGetParameter("cities")),[Delimiter=",", Columns=2, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Name", type text}, {"City", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

*cars query*

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(fnGetParameter("cars")),[Delimiter=",", Columns=2, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Name", type text}, {"Car", type text}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"Name"}, cities, {"Name"}, "cities", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded cities" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "cities", {"City"}, {"City"})
in
    #"Expanded cities"
```

The needed output is the top left merged table:
[image: Needed output]

It didn't help to use a middleman by replacing:

```
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(fnGetParameter("cars")),
```

With:

```
middleman = File.Contents(fnGetParameter("cars"),
Source = Csv.Document(middleman),
```

Or

```
middleman=fnGetParameter("cars"),
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(middleman),
```

[image: Blocked by firewall]

When I choose to overly ignore privacy levels, it of course works, but I rather not go that path, especially as it seems to be saved not in the file but in the registry under the specific file path in a specific computer.

[image: Query Options]
[image: Ignore the Privacy Levels]

Is there another way to avoid the firewall error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interim solution is running this VBA to temporarily disable the firewall:

```
ThisWorkbook.Queries.FastCombine = True
...refresh connections or edit queries
ThisWorkbook.Queries.FastCombine = False
```